# Aggregate 2 collections to parent / child

Tags: c#, parent-child

I'm not sure if the way I found to solve this problem is a good one or not.

Example scenario:

```
class FolderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FileItem[] Files { get; set; }
}

class FileItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Starting from 2 collections:

```
FolderItem[] folders = 
    new FolderItem[]
    {
        new FolderItem
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Folder1"
        },
        new FolderItem
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Folder2"
        }
    };

FileItem[] files = 
    new FileItem[]
    {
        new FileItem
        {
            Id = 100,
            FolderId = 1,
            Name = "file1.txt",
            Content = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        },
        new FileItem
        {
            Id = 200,
            FolderId = 1,
            Name = "file2.txt",
            Content = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        },
        new FileItem
        {
            Id = 300,
            FolderId = 2,
            Name = "file3.txt",
            Content = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        },
        new FileItem
        {
            Id = 400,
            FolderId = 2,
            Name = "file4.txt",
            Content = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        }
    };
```

In order to put 'FileItem' into the property 'Files' of 'Folder', I do:

```
 files
    .Join
    (
        folders,
        x => x.FolderId,
        x => x.Id,
        (x,y) => new { File = x, Folder = y }
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.Folder.Id)
    .Select
    (x => 
        { 
            var folder = x.First().Folder;
            folder.Files = x.Select(z => z.File).ToArray();
            return folder;
        }
    )
```

I can use `.First()` in the `GroupBy` lambda because I'm grouping by its id

I get:

[image]

Is there some extension method that can do quicker or better than this? Are there any best practices?

Comment: why don't you only change the  `public FileItem Files { get; set; }` property to a collection `public List<FileItem> Files { get; set; }`

Comment: That's a mistake in my example, I'll edit the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new list, using `Where` to get the files for each folder.

```
var foldersWithFiles = folders
    .Select
    (
        folder =>
        new FolderItem
        {
            Id = folder.Id,
            Name = folder.Name,
            Files = files.Where
            (
                file => file.FolderId = folder.Id
            ).ToArray()
        )
    );
```

You can always replace the old list afterward, like this:

```
folders = foldersWithFiles.ToArray();
```

Comment: Compared with 1 million items, your solution wins 00:00:00.0000193 against  00:00:00.0027583 of mine. Complete test case here: https://pastebin.com/nZLqaS3Q

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop the folders and add the items in their respective folders.
First you would need to change `FileItem[]` into `List<FileItem>` and `FolderItem[]` into `List<FolderItem>` everywhere.

You will need a remove and get extension method for `List` like this one. This is optimized to remove element while still returning them which reduce the amount
of subsequent iterations.

```
public static List<T> RemoveAndGet<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var itemsRemoved = new List<T>();

    // iterate backward for performance
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // keep item pointer
        var item = list[i];

        // if the item match the remove predicate
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            // add the item to the returned list
            itemsRemoved.Add(item);

            // remove the item from the source list
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    return itemsRemoved;
}
```

Then your only query is to populate the current folders you have with this query.

```
 folders.ForEach(folder => 
     folder.Files.AddRange(files.RemoveAndGet(file => file.FolderId == folder.Id)));
```

Comment: This will remove elements from the starting collection, won't it?

Comment: @Phate01 yes it will. If you have thousands of files you will be happy that the list to search for is getting smaller and smaller. You can always keep a copy of the list somewhere if you need it by simply doing `var copy = new List<FileItem>(files)`